# Replace GET parameters in url based on position (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the GET parameters of a url,

The url's are in this format:

`https://url.com?remove_parameter={VALUE}`

`https://url.com?keep_parameter={VALUE}&remove_parameter={VALUE}`

what am I looking for:

`https://url.com`

`https://url.com?keep_parameter={VALUE}`

I looked for regex expressions but can't find the proper answer.

Is there a way to use a regex in javascript's replace function to format these url's?

Comment: For your second comment, `?keep_parameter={VALUE}` is a GET parameter, but it's still included. Was this intentional, or should it be removed too?

Comment: It should be kept.

Comment: Are you only looking to remove the last GET parameter then, i.e. the final one in the url, leaving the rest in place?

Comment: I am looking to remove a specific parameter, for example &click_id={VALUE} , it is present not necessarily at the end. I can use the replace("?click_id={VALUE}", "") but this covers only the case when the click_id parameters is first, I am looking for a regex that can cover both cases, with "?" and "&"

Comment: Maybe you should use an URL parser instead of regex.

Comment: For example with a quick search on github, https://github.com/lil-js/uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely do this without using regular expressions.

```js
var url = new URL("https://url.com?keep_parameter={VALUE}&remove_parameter={VALUE}");

console.log(url.origin);

console.log("Before removal:");
url.searchParams.forEach(function(value, key){ console.log(key, value); });

url.searchParams.delete('remove_parameter');

console.log("After removal:");
url.searchParams.forEach(function(value, key){ console.log(key, value); });

console.log("Rebuild:");
console.log(url.toString());
```

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
[&?]remove_parameter={[^}]*}
```

substituted with an empty string would simply work OK here.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uypFiV/1/)

```js
const regex = /[&?]remove_parameter={[^}]*}/gm;
const str = `https://url.com?remove_parameter={VALUE}
https://url.com?keep_parameter={VALUE}&remove_parameter={VALUE}
http://url.com?remove_parameter={VALUE}
https://www.url.com?keep_parameter={VALUE}&remove_parameter={VALUE}`;
const subst = ``;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Not quite: With `https://url.com?remove_parameter={VALUE}&keep_parameter={VALUE}` you'll end up with `https://url.com&keep_parameter={VALUE}`. You wanted `?` instead of `&`. (This task has been complicated by the fact that someone decided it would be a good idea to use one character for the first separator in query strings and a different character for subsequent separators.)